# How to edit first and last keyframe in the graph editor seamless for a looping animation?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image]

This ia short animation loop where a ball floats up and down on the surface of the water. And the middle keyframe is where an outside force slightly pushes it up the water. So the ball floats up with a little more speed then down and this repeats.
My issue right now is that the at the point where B loops back to A, the motion doesn't look smooth.
Is there a trick to making the graph's flow from keyframe B to keyframe A smooth and seamless without manually having to do trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate the keyframe A:

[image]